# How to parse the output and store it into a variable

Tags: linux, shell, parsing

How can I get the value 8.4.1 from the below command and store it to a variable using shell script.

```
   [root@testserver bin]# ./psql --version

   **psql (PostgreSQL) 8.4.1**

   contains support for command-line editing

   [root@testserver bin]#
```

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LINE=`psql --version | grep -oE "[0-9\.]+"` && echo $LINE

grep - print lines matching a pattern
-E - using regex
-o - showing only matching result, not a whole line
[0-9\.]+ - regex, which find a string with numbers and dots
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply edem...can you please tell me what exactly grep -oE "([0-9\.])+" means for.

Comment: Updated in the answer.